# Why I cannot bind to scoped ipv6 any address?

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6

I'm trying to learn coding in IPv6 to be able to support both IPv6 and IPv4 via IPv4-mapped addresses in my small server. I want to bind to specific interface, but I have a strange problem. If I try to bind to a IPv6 on a interface with a scope (like `fe80::8d65:c06f:b189:a314%9`), it works. But if I try to bind to any address for same interface (like `::%9`), binding fails. Any idea why this happens?

Here is my test code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  struct addrinfo hints;
  struct addrinfo *result;
  int s = 0, r =  0;
  int v6flag = 0;
  char str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

  if (argc <2) {
    printf("insufficient arguments\n");
    return -1;
  }

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; /* Datagram socket */
  hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICSERV | AI_NUMERICHOST;
  hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;

  r = getaddrinfo(argv[1], "40444", &hints, &result);
  if (r != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
    return -1;
  }

  s = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
  if (s <= 0) {
    printf("error socket\n");
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    return -1;
  }

  if (setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &v6flag, sizeof(v6flag)) != 0) {
    printf("opt error: %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    close(s);
    return -1;
  }

  if (bind(s, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen) == 0) {
    printf("bound!\n");
    struct sockaddr_in6 in6;
    unsigned int sz = sizeof(in6);
    memset(&in6, 0, sizeof(in6));
    if (getsockname(s, (struct sockaddr*)&in6, &sz) == 0) {
      printf("got addr\n");
      if (inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(in6.sin6_addr), str, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN) != 0)
        printf("addr is: %s\n", str);
    }
  }
  else {
    printf("erro: %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
  }

  freeaddrinfo(result);
  close(s);

  return 0;
}
```

Any idea why I cannot bind to something like `::%9`? In addition, is it possible to bind an interface **without** any IPv6 addresses with my code at all (for example using IPv4-mapped address of the interface)?

Comment: I just tried your code under Ubuntu 20 - it works perfectly using `::%2` (on my computer, the Ethernet card has scope `%2`). Maybe it depends on the operating system if it is possible to bind to `::%scope`.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: @MartinRosenau hm.....I guess you are right. I was trying this code under **WSL1** Ubuntu 20.04 and it didn't work. But after your comment, I tried it on a pure Ubuntu system, it worked. My bad I guess.... But should I be able to bind on an interface without any assigned ipv6 with `::%n`?

Comment: The IPv4-Mapped addresses are in the `::ffff:0:0/96` range, and they are _not_ IPv6 addresses, only an IPv6 notation for IPv4 addresses so they can use the same data store, e.g. database,. and they are reserved by IPv6, cannot be used as source or destination addresses, and cannot be routed. The IPv4-Compatible addresses (`::/96`) have been deprecated for years. See the _[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)_.

Comment: Remember that IPv4 and IPv6 are two completely separate, incompatible protocols, and trying to apply IPv4-thinking to IPv6 will fail. IPv6 requires some different ways of doing things, and you should be familiar with the RFCs for it prior to releasing code.

Comment: @RonMaupin I was using `64:ff9b::/96` as IPv4-mapped ones which seems is a IPv4/IPv6 translation address. I didn't know that I cannot use them as source or destination. too bad....

Comment: You need a device to do the translation, you cannot simply use the addressing. You need to read and understand the RFCs around that. IPv4 and IPv6 are two completely separate, incompatible protocols, and it is complicated to translate packets from one to the other. Remember that 128-bit addresses cannot be crammed into a 32-bit address. Also, IPv6 does not have many of the header fields that IPv4 uses. There is an entire series of RFCs around translation.